# Is it possible to use V8 in ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, v8

Since ASP (Active Server Pages) seems to be supported for at least 10 years, would it be possible to run ASP on [V8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine))? (Have anyone tried that?)

(Note: I know that there is node.js or owin and advantages of these:)

UPDATE: According to Wikipedia it also [supports third party scripting languages for instance PerlScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages#Summary). So, it seems to me that scripting layer is provided by a COM, therefore it might by possible to create COM wrapper for V8 that could be used in ASP.

Comment: as far as i know V8 -- it's google javascript engine, and it's not related to ASP. ASP it's propriety Microsoft technology, server side.

Comment: V8?  care to elaborate on what that is ?

Comment: @Dee Please see tag.

Comment: If V8 supports [ActiveX Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Scripting) then your answer is **Yes**.

Comment: @Lankymart Only what is needed is to implement wrapper for V8 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xawadt95%28v=vs.94%29.aspx), or does it need something more? (It seems that it could be also useful for Windows scripting: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/7E1DqOoClAs)

Comment: @TN The problem is going to be finding any information on how to do it. When I've looked in the past I've only ever been able to find existing implementations like [ActivePerl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActivePerl) for example.

Comment: @TN Might find this a useful read. [Chapter 6 - Developing Web Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742411.aspx)

Comment: @Lankymart Add your first and second comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: This isn't classic asp, but there's a v8.net project if it's of any interest https://v8dotnet.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many people have said Classic ASP supports both VBScript and JScript (Microsoft's implementation of the ECMAScript standard) out of the box.

This doesn't mean that you can't use other scripting languages with Classic ASP, but finding information on how to implement what Microsoft coins an *"Active Scripting" (Originally called "ActiveX Scripting")*  language is going to be difficult.

[image: Active Scripting Stack]

The only information I have been able to find that may help is [ActivePerl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActivePerl) which has an Active Scripting language component of Perl called PerlScript.

If you do have an Active Scripting language installed in IIS other then VBScript or JavaScript you can use the ASP Processing Directive [@LANGUAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524311(v=vs.90).aspx) to switch to using them.

---

So in conclusion;

If V8 supports Active Scripting then the answer is **Yes**.

---

**Useful Links**

- [Active Scripting (Wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Scripting)
- [Chapter 6 - Developing Web Applications (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742411.aspx)
- [Windows Script Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdee6589(v=vs.94).aspx) *(recommended reading)*

Answer (score 1):

If by V8 you mean the javascript engine which comes with Google Chome then no. Classic ASP supports either VBScript or Javascript as its scripting language.  Basically what is available server side is what Internet Explorer can use client side.

If you're using Javascript with Classic ASP then you're using Microsoft's own implementation - JScript - rather than V8

If by V8 you mean IIS8 then yes, ASP runs fine on IIS8.  It's not enabled by default, you need to enable it through IIS manager

Comment: @TN These are the default out of the box languages, but other implementations are available. The Classic ASP ISAPI can support any scripting language that supports `ActiveX Scripting`. Depending on what scripting languages you have installed you can switch using the [`@LANGUAGE` ASP Processing Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524311(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: @Lankymart Is PerlScript still available in the ActiveState distribution?  I played with it a few years back on my XP machine, but it's not included in their latest 64 bit version, I dont know about 32 bit.  They've also dropped asp support from their Python distributions

Comment: @John To be honest with you not sure but it's the closest thing I could find. The point remains Classic ASP is capable of supporting other scripting engines, but as ASP was deprecated sometime ago now finding information on how to do it will be a challenge.