# Two types of VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

So recently, I had a friend teach me some VBScript. This is the following code.

```vb
help = MsgBox("Click on 'Yes'",vbYesNoCancel, "Orders")
WScript.Echo help
```

The file is called `File.vbs` and as far as I know `.vbs` stands for Visual Basic Script file. But recently, I've been searching on the internet and find VBS to be another thing. It looks like `html` or `xml`. Something like this.

```
<% Option Explicit
 %><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>VBScript Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><% 
        ' Grab current time from Now() function.
                ' An '=' sign occurring after a context switch (<%) is shorthand 
                ' for a call to the Write() method of the Response object.
        Dim timeValue = Now %>
        The time, in 24-hour format, is 
                <%=Hour(timeValue)%>:<%=Minute(timeValue)%>:<%=Second(timeValue)%>.
        </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Can someone explain if I'm looking at the correct language or something?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: that is `ASP` before `ASP.NET` so it's now refereed to as `Classic ASP`, to run `ASP` you would have to setup `IIS`

Comment: The second snippet is Classic ASP (essentially server-side VBScript for dynamically generating web pages).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not two types of VBScript, the difference is purely in the context of how it is used.

The [VBScript Scripting Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) cannot run standalone: it has a dependency on a Scripting Host which can take various forms depending on the context of its execution.

For client-side scenarios there are a few ways it can be used:

1. Through the [Windows Scripting Host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) which can execute `.vbs` and `.wsf` extension files *(for more on WSF see [Windows Script File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_File))*.
2. Through Internet Explorer *(deprecated from Microsoft Edge onwards to bring it in line with Modern Standards Browsers)* via the `<script>` HTML tag.
3. Through an [HTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) which is similar to Internet Explorer but is less restrictive and designed to be used in controlled environments where access to local resources (which would otherwise be considered unsafe) is allowed. It's typically used for designing web-based interfaces to use within an Enterprise *(the `mshta.exe` is included in most versions of Windows)*.

For server-side scenarios the options are more straightforward:

- [Classic ASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) is a server-side script engine that incorporates VBScript as its default scripting language. Classic ASP runs as an ISAPI extension inside [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) and can be configured to process any [Active Scripting Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Scripting) *(which to date includes VBScript and JScript, but there is also a custom implementation of Perl known as [PerlScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActivePerl) that will run on a non-IIS based server)*.

  In the second example, the weird brackets around the VBScript `<%` and `%>` are part of the Classic ASP Script Engine. They are known as an "Inline Code Block": they help the Classic ASP Interpreter identify what code it needs to process before the final HTML is returned by the Web Server. It would be wrong to call Classic ASP VBScript, as it has its own object model which is completely independent of VBScript — it incorporates objects such as `Request`, `Response` and `Server` that can only be used in the context of Classic ASP.

---

#### Useful Links

- [A: VBScript support in Internet Explorer 11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17532816/692942)
- [A: Is it possible to use V8 in ASP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26783132/692942) *(explanation of the architecture of Classic ASP)*